# how to write objective-c function

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, switch-statement

I use the following code for switching the views

```
- (void)loading2menu{

[UIView beginAnimations:@"Loading2Menu" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

if (self.menuViewController.view.superview == nil)
{
    if (self.menuViewController == nil)
    {
        MenuViewController *menuController = 
        [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuView" 
                                             bundle:nil];
        self.menuViewController = menuController;
        [menuController release];
    }

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:
     UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                           forView:self.view cache:YES];

    [loadingViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
    [menuViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
    [loadingViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:menuViewController.view atIndex:0];
    [menuViewController viewDidDisappear:YES];
    [loadingViewController viewDidAppear:YES];
}
else
{
    if (self.loadingViewController == nil)
    {
        LoadingViewController *loadingController = 
        [[LoadingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingView" 
                                                bundle:nil];
        self.loadingViewController = loadingController;
        [loadingController release];
    }

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:
     UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                           forView:self.view cache:YES];

    [menuViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
    [loadingViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
    [menuViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:loadingViewController.view atIndex:0];
    [loadingViewController viewDidDisappear:YES];
    [menuViewController viewDidAppear:YES];        
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

i think it is too many codes,and also if i have more views to switch,i must write more codes like that,it waste time,and it is not the best way to do this,so i write a function for doing the same thing

```
- (void)switchtheviews:(UIViewController*)coming over:(UIViewController*)going {    
[UIView beginAnimations:@"frame" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];   
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:viewController.view cache:YES];
[coming viewWillAppear:YES];
[going viewWillDisappear:YES];
[going.view removeFromSuperview];
[viewController.view insertSubview:coming.view atIndex:0];
[going viewDidDisappear:YES];
[coming viewDidAppear:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];

  }
```

so,how can i call this function? if i use the old one,i can use

```
[[MyAppsAppDelegate App].switchViewController loading2menu];
```

but this new one ,what should i write for calling the new function?thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  Are you just trying to replace one view with another?

Comment: yes,i just trying to replace one view with another by writing less code. i also want to know how can i call the function "switchtheviews" in the code,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a C function like this:

```
void switchtheviews(UIViewController *coming, UIViewController *going)
{
...
/* there is no self here */
...
}
```

And use it anywhere in your code:

`switchtheviews(v1, v2);`

I don't think this is what you want. You can write a private method to do the same thing and keep everything encapsulated in your class. Try something like this on your `.m` file (it's private stuff, no need to put it on the `.h`):

```
// MegaCoolViewController.m

@interface MegaCoolViewController ()

- (void)_switchtheviews:(UIViewController*)coming over:(UIViewController*)going;

@end


@implementation MegaCoolViewController

#pragma mark - Private

- (void)_switchtheviews:(UIViewController*)coming over:(UIViewController*)going
{
/* do your thing, use self freely */
}

@end
```

As you can read in other answers, there are easier ways to switch views. I'm just answering the syntax part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to be using animations for what you're doing.  It should just be something like:

```
[objectName removeFromSuperview];
[superViewName addSubview:otherView];
```

To call your function, it should be:

```
[object switchTheViews:viewController over:otherViewController];
```